# Mouseenter and Mouseleave on elements added with AJAX

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I have a gallery with different divs. They have a mouseenter and mouseleave function that adds a class to the elements.

The problem comes when I click on a link that sends a new gallery with a load() method. While the divs have the same classes the mouseenter and mouseleave stops working and no classes are added. Is there a way to fix this?

**HTML**

```
 ...

 <section class="categories">
     <ul class="categoryList">
       <li class="selected HTML"> HTML & CSS </li>
       <li class="Javascript"> Javascript </li>
       <li class="JQuery"> JQuery </li>
       <li class="APIs"> APIs </li>

       </ul>
     </section><!--categories-->

  </div><!--leftColumn-->

  <div class="mainSection">
    <div class="wrapper">
    <h1 id="mainSectionTitle"> HTML & CSS </h1>
      <hr class="hr">


      <div class="gallery">

     <!-- Items are inserted here -->  

       </div><!--gallery-->
      </div><!--wrapper-->
     </div><!--mainSection-->

  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
  $(".gallery").load("HTML-CSS.html");


  $(".categoryList li").click(function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
    $("#mainSectionTitle").addClass("animate-inLeft");
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
     $(".wrapper h1").text(text);
    setTimeout(timeOut, 700);
   });


 function timeOut(){
  $("#mainSectionTitle").removeClass("animate-inLeft")
 }

$(".thumb").mouseenter(function(){
   $(".opacityParagraph").addClass("opacityParagraphVisible")
    $(this).css("opacity", "0.1");
 })

    $(".thumb").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).css("opacity", "1");
$(".opacityParagraph").removeClass("opacityParagraphVisible")
  })


$(".Javascript").click(function(){

    $(".gallery").load("Javascript.html");

});
```

This is one of the examples being loaded in the gallery, if I place it from the start then the mouseenter and mouseleea works just fine, just not after it's dinamically added:

```
<div class="opacityLayer">  
     <p class="opacityParagraph">   </p>
   <div class="thumb"> <a href="..."> <img src="ProjectImages/HTML-CSS/flexbox-gallery.JPG"></a><p></p></div></div>
```

Comment: Try `$(".gallery").on("mouseover",".thumb", function(){})` and same with `mouseleave`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know that that should work for dynamically added elements but it doesn't in my case. The only thing that is working for now which is a bad solution is to add a <script> tag at the end of every HTML file that I'm calling.